# How to execute multiple update queries once in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have more than 100000 update queries need to be execute, `db.collection_name.update(upsert=True)` can only execute one query statement,it is too slow  if I execute all queries one by one.

Is there any way to collect multiple queries into a list then execute once in pymongo?

I tried use [bulk](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html), and it doesn't save any time, also not a transaction operation :(

Here is my code snippet:

```
bulk = self._db.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
for user_id, result in results.items():
    time_stamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S')
    history = {
        'create_at': time_stamp,
        'results': result
    }
    bulk.find({'user_id': user_id}).update(
        {'$set': {'update_at': time_stamp}}
    )
    bulk.find({'user_id': user_id}).update(
        {'$addToSet': {'history': history}}
    )
bulk.execute()
```

it is almost the same speed as following update statement:

```
self._db.update(
    {'user_id': user_id},
    {'$set': {'update_at':time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S')}}, 
    upsert=True
)
self._db.update(
    {'user_id': user_id},
    {'$addToSet': {'history': history}},
    upsert=True
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could introduce a counter variable that ensures the updates are sent in batches because write commands can accept no more than 1000 operations so there's need to group operations to have at most 1000 operations and re-intialise the bulk operation when the loop hits the 1000 iteration. Also, DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself): merge the update statements `$set` and `$addToSet` into one update document. Your final update script should perform much better:

```
bulk = self._db.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
counter = 0;

for user_id, result in results.items():
    time_stamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S')
    history = {
        'create_at': time_stamp,
        'results': result
    }
    bulk.find({'user_id': user_id}).update({
        '$set': { 'update_at': time_stamp },
        '$addToSet': { 'history': history }
    })
    counter++

    if (counter % 1000 == 0):
        bulk.execute()
        bulk = self._db.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()

if (counter % 1000 != 0):
    bulk.execute()
```

Comment: Thanks for your DRY proposal! I just didn't realize that the update statement can be merged. And I also tried your bulk suggestion, it didn't work for saving time, almost the same unfortunately. Even if it works, then it also not elegant due to the update bulk still execute one by one, what if I have 10 million updates? Is there any method to passing an array of query statements as the update argument?

Comment: You are probably missing the point with bulk updates; instead of sending every update request to the server, the bulk sends once in every 1000 operations hence the better performance that without. Using the bulk API is more efficient because of the above. Try doing a synthetic micro-benchmark, updating 1000 records without the bulk API vs with. With the Bulk API you can do an estimated 4000 operations per second and with 10,000,000 documents being updated (around 5000 operations per second) it's quite a boost for doing large numbers of operations, as long as the class of operation is the same.

Comment: Well, here are some interesting results of a benchmark (use time.clock()-start): Perform a pre-task: 147.572841 Updates Time of self._db.update(): 5.057265 Updates Time of bulk.find().update(): 0.736898 Total: 153.379147 The output shows bulk did same time. BUT, HOWEVER, I didn’t observe an acceleration! When I use my stopwatch to record the actual time when each output content appear: Perform a pre-task: 2 min 27 s Updates Time of self._db.update(): 1 min 33 s Updates Time of bulk.find().update(): 2 min 18 s What’s going on here? Why the updates statement time results didn’t match?